# Django, Javascript: passing data disables functions inside app

Tags: javascript, django

I'm aware that a lot of people asked a similiar question, but none of these helped me with my problem!? Inside my view I'm passing the name of the active user...

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    user_name = f"{user.first_name} {user.last_name}"
    json_data = json.dumps(user_name)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {"user_name": json_data})
```

**script.js**

```
let user_name = {{user_name|safe}};
```

But when trying to attach the data to my variable inside javascript, I'm getting the following error and all of my other functions inside js stop working!

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Comment: The JS file isn't going through the Django view renderer. It won't receive the data, and you also can't use template syntax in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...dunno if this is a propper solution for my problem, but at least now it's working as it should! I'm passing the data into my *index.html*, so that I'm able to access it further down the line inside my *script.js*!

**index.html**

```
<script>
    let username = {{ user_name|safe }};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '...' %}"></script>
```